# How to serialize a django model with several self referenceing fields with a depth of 1

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How do I serialize my model without an endless recursion? I only want to replace foreign keys with one row deep of information.

Currently I have this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    my_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    last_update = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    friend_1  = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        related_name="friend_1a",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to_field="my_id",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    friend_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        related_name="friend_2a",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to_field="my_id",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    friend_3 = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        related_name="friend_3a",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to_field="my_id",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    def _get_days_since_last_review(self):
        today = date.today()
        if self.last_update is None:
            self.last_update = today
        return str((today - self.last_update).days)

    days_since_last_review = property(_get_days_since_last_review)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ClientSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=500)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=500)
    days_since_last_review = serializers.CharField(max_length=500)
    friend_1 = serializers.CharField()
    friend_2 = serializers.CharField()
    friend_3 = serializers.CharField()


class ClientSerializerWithFriends(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ this is a recursive infinite loop. TODO: Fix Me! """
    friend_1 = RecursiveField(allow_null=True)
    friend_2 = RecursiveField(allow_null=True)
    friend_3 = RecursiveField(allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = (
            "my_id",
            "name",
            "days_since_last_review",
            "competitor_1",
            "competitor_2",
            "competitor_3",
        )
```

but I can't seem to find a way to limit the `RecursiveField()` to one level of depth. Currently it reaches the max depth of recursion because friends are reciprocal.

Basically JSON of it would be:

```
[{
    "my_id": "LH7K_T",
    "name": "Jack",
    "last_update": "2019-06-03",
    "days_since_last_review": "9",
    "friend_1": {
        "id": 6,
        "my_id": "4YR0_T",
        "name": "Austin",
        "last_update": "2019-06-03",
        "friend_1": "LH7K_T",
        "friend_2": "M5XQ2o",
        "friend_3": null
    },
    "competitor_2": {
        "id": 8,
        "my_id": "C3ogRZ",
        "name": "Flo",
        "last_update": "2019-06-04",
        "friend_1": "LH7K_T",
        "friend_2": "0vYgr4",
        "friend_3": "M5XQ2o"
    },
    "competitor_3": {
        "id": 7,
        "my_id": "M5XQ2o",
        "name": "Charlotte",
        "last_update": "2019-06-02",
        "friend_1": "LH7K_T",
        "friend_2": null,
        "friend_3": null
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [**`depth = 1`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) in Serializer's Meta class:

```
class ClientSerializerWithFriends(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = (
            "my_id",
            "name",
            "days_since_last_review",
            "friend_1",
            "friend_2",
            "friend_3",
        )
        depth = 1
```

Comment: That didn't change anything; I still get a  `RecursionError:` . Even setting  `depth = 0`  didn't affect it either.

Comment: Did you remov RecursiveField?